# MySQL Database in Multiple Operating Systems

Tags: mysql, linux

If i have a dual-boot system (XP and Ubuntu) with a shared data partition to store the database files in, is it possible to get both XP's and Linux's MySQL using the same database file when each one boots? Would it be as simple as changing the *datadir* setting in each configuration file and ensuring all other settings match? Would I need to add any data to the MySQL relation continuously or just when a table or database is created or deleted?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MySQL documentation:

http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_File_Formats

"...The .frm format is the same on all platforms..."

So in theory you could, but I would make a lot of tests with a copy of the database files first to be 99% sure, specially if you're on a 64 bits system and the XP and Linux versions are different (for example, XP 32 bits and Ubuntu 64 bits.)